# Data types not as expected after using AS with GENERATE

Tags: apache-pig

I am having trouble getting this simple filter to work. It worked before I declared a schema (left out the chararray parts); however now it won't work, and I know that the field is definitely a string value. Some say 'COMPLETE' and others say 'INCOMPLETE'..... It reads all the records in, but finds none when I filter;

```
A = load 'file' USING PigStorage('|');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $48 as wr_sts:chararray,$49 as wr_sts_qlfctn:chararray, $50 as    comment:chararray, $17 as id:chararray;
C = FILTER B BY wr_sts == 'COMPLETE';
```

This doesn't bring back any records, which I know exist....

When I dump B, it does in fact dump correct records to the screen. So the filter relation is the one that is broken for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an `AS` clause while `LOAD`ing data, Pig parses your data into the correct data types and applies the schema you gave. When you use an `AS` clause in a `GENERATE` statement, Pig does **not** cast into the indicated type; it just updates the schema.

Thus, while Pig believes that `wr_sts` is a `chararray`, internally it is still stored as a `bytearray` and the comparison always fails. If you were instead to do the following, it would behave as expected:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (chararray) $48 as wr_sts, $49 as wr_sts_qlfctn:chararray, $50 as    comment:chararray, $17 as id:chararray;
```

Note that `$48` is cast to a `chararray`. This not only tells Pig to treat it as a `chararray` in the schema for purposes of parsing the script, it actually converts the underlying Java object from a `byte[]` to a `String`.

Comment: worked like a charm; very informative, I had no idea the data type did not get casted on the GENERATE statement. cheers.